# Single-word alternative to "that required intervention"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to describe a process that, though intended to be fully automated, instead required human intervention in a particular instance, owing to unspecified difficulties with the process. I'm looking for a single word to replace X in this sentence:

> This meeting is to discuss *X* processes.

where the sense of the sentence is

> This meeting is to discuss processes **that required intervention**.

I also want to avoid anything that has significant negative connotations. For example, *bungled* might be accurate, but wouldn't work in this case.

What is a single-word alternative to the phrase "that required intervention"?

Comment: Maybe *quasi-automated*.

Comment: stalled, halted, derailed, inefficient?  This meeting is to discuss process exceptions? This meeting is to discuss process exception handling?

Comment: @Brad I actually like the term *exception* a lot, but maybe that's because I'm a programmer at heart. I'm not sure if other readers would quite understand what an *exceptional process* meant.

Comment: An informal term is *tweaking*. But it refers to the correction rather than the need to be manually adjusted.

Comment: Perhaps you could say "rescued" processes to convey the idea that an unexpected intervention was required (and performed).

Comment: @PellMel I like *rescued*; *salvaged*, or *recovered* might be good as well.

Comment: The original asked for a word to replace *X*. The new form is ambiguous - does it ask for a word to replace *X* or to replace the phrase *that required intervention*? X would be the human processes, but the processes "that required intervention" would be the automatic processes that failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sub-optimal**

Shows that everything was not as smooth as could be, but does not overly bring a negative connotation.

Comment: *Suboptimal* is probably the suggestion that's closest to what I was looking for, but actually I think *substandard* would be even better. It indicates that the process as implemented does not meet our standards, as these processes are supposed to be fully automated. (although I grant *substandard* has negative connotations)

Answer (score 1):

This answer suggests words for the replacement process, not the process that failed.

Try "This meeting is to discuss *contingency* processes".

> **Contingency** *noun*
>   1.1 A provision for a possible event or circumstance
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingency)

Since the processes require human intervention, you can simply call them *manual* processes (as opposed to *automated* processes).

> **Manual** *adjective*
>   1.1 (Of a device) operated or controlled by hand, rather than automatically or electronically
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/manual)

Here's an example of its use in a *business continuity planning* context (emphasis mine):

> For an automated administrative process, it may be considered adequate to back up the business process with a **manual process** supported by stand-alone PCs.
>   [pp 133,134, John Rittinghouse and James F Ransome, Business Continuity and Disaster Recovery for InfoSec Managers](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=jm2PNUr_w_QC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=%22manual%20process%22%20continuity&source=bl&ots=2WC2n-LCgb&sig=eoNDnMElTYZQL4_kOIlrPNxve4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXrL2Rl_bLAhWKG5QKHc6RDFMQ6AEIPDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22manual%20process%22%20continuity&f=false)

Comment: I like the term *contingency*, but it doesn't exactly fit my needs. In this case, the *contingency process* is the manual steps that were needed because the original process failed.

Comment: @p.s.w.g In that case, you can simply call them *manual* processes. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calling it "failed." Negative connotations or not, that's what happened.

Answer (score 0):

**disjointed processes.**

> In this way, when the system is again allowed to free-run, following a
>   debugging sequence, it can react to the fresh input as a complete
>   system, rather than as a set of disjointed processes.

Ada in Transition: Proceedings of the 1992 Ada UK International Conference ...
By W. J. Taylor

Answer (score 0):

Suggest the verb **troubleshoot** (usually seen as the noun **troubleshooting**):

Defn. 1.1 - trace and correct faults in a mechanical or electronic system

> *'The service plan also provides remote system troubleshooting and preventative maintenance to uncover potential problems before they occur.'*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/troubleshoot)

The example sentence, above, becomes:

> *'This meeting is to discuss troubleshooting.'*